How to return document reference of a newly created document from repository to ViewModel in Java?
When I create a new document in the repository using database.collection("Groups").document(id).set(group) and try to return the document reference doing database.collection("Groups").document(id) referring to the newly created document, I cannot fetch the document since firebase Firestore works asynchronously due to which the the .set is still adding the new document and I unintentionally return the document reference before it.
Things I have tried

Returning a LiveData from the repository, but that's not the job of the repository
Added LiveData in ViewModel, but ViewModel should not alter the database (by adding a new document here, in the Firestore database)
I saw about Task.await, but it blocks the main thread

I expect to return a DocumentReference from the repository to the ViewModel so that I can post its value on my MutableLiveData in ViewModel

Firebase APIs are all asynchronous, so you would accomplish this just like any other async job in a repository. Use a listener on the task to find out when it completes. If you're using kotlin, consider taking time to learn about coroutines and flows.

If you want to create a document ID that can be later used for writing some data in a collection in  Firestore, then you have to generate the document ID first:
val db = Firebase.firestore
val groupsRef = db.collection("Groups")
val docId = groupsRef.document().id

And then use it in a DocumentReference object:
val docIdRef = groupsRef.document(docId)

To add the data in Firestore, simply use:
docIdRef.set(group).addOnCompleteListener { setTask ->
    if (setTask.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Document added successfully.")
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "Error adding document ${setTask.exception?.message}")
    }
}

If you want to read the document that was recently added, then you have to perform a Query#get() call only when the operation of adding the data to Firstore is complete:
docIdRef.set(group).addOnCompleteListener { setTask ->
    if (setTask.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Document added successfully.")

        //Read the data inside the callback.
        docIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { getTask ->
            if (getTask.isSuccessful) {
                val document = getTask.result
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Document data: ${document.data}")
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "No such document")

                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Error getting document ${getTask.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "Error adding document ${setTask.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!

    }
}

If you want to simplify the above operations, as also @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, I recommend you take a look at Kotlin Coroutines and Asynchronous Flow.

Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?
